# How to start and run a python script during boot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

First, I apologize for my bad English and now my problem :
at the moment I try that my python script camera.py should autostart after the boot has been finished.

However, I tried using rc.local, .bashrc and init.d but nothing will work. Does someone have a better solution, so my script autostarts.

Here you can see the line that I add in my rc.local. Before this line are only blue comments

```
sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/camera.py &
exit 0
```

Here is the .bashrc that I used. I only add on the last line of .bashrc those two lines:

```
echo Running at boot 
sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/camera.py
```

Comment: Can you post your rc.local and/or bashrc file?

Comment: Of course. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it has been added to the end of the `.bashrc`?

1.Make sure you are in the pi folder:

```
$ cd ~
```

2.To open up .bashrc for configuration:

```
$ sudo nano .bashrc
```

Scroll down to the bottom and add the line: `python ~/Desktop/camera.py`

Save and exit: Ctrl+X, Y, Enter

then reset your pi

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering. You are right,I didn't write the line on the bottom. Now it is working.

Comment: @DizzySailor that is great! I’m glad I could help. If you would be able to mark my answer as correct. It might help someone else having the same issue resolve there issue too

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting it as a chron job. Check this out: https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/

This will make it run independent of your user login to a shell. Specifically, look at the `@reboot` section.

Comment: Hey thank you for answering. I tried using your idea but after I reboot my raspberry, he wrote a kernel panic. So what could that be

Comment: I'm not sure, considering I run automated tasks on a Raspberry Pi myself in such a way without issues. I'd suggest maybe posting that issue (separately); if you add more information to it and tag me, I'll gladly take a look.